# Projectors of unbounded operators in *-algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

Let's suppose we have a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and the C*-algebra of the set of bounded operators $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. For what I have understood, unbounded operators as for example position $\hat{x}$ and momentum $\hat{p}$ operators enter in the algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ as generators of strongly continuous group of unitary operators. Can we say that the projectors into the eigenstates of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?

**Edit**

For eigenstates of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ I mean here the vectors that approximate as close as you want to eigenstates of the unbounded operators

Comment: What do you mean by "projectors into the eigenstates"? The whole difficulty of operators with continuous spectrum like $x$ and $p$ is that they do not *have* eigenstates inside of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: You are right, but I think that it is possible to find "approximate" eigenstates which are as close as possible to eigenstates of these operators. Let me edit the question so to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct notion of "projectors" for self-adjoint operators with continuous spectrum is via their [spectral measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure#Extensions_of_projection-valued_measures,_integrals_and_the_spectral_theorem). For any $A$, there is a projection-valued measure $\mathrm{d}\pi_A$ on $\mathbb{R}$ supported on the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of $A$. For any measureable $\Omega\subset \sigma(A)$, the projector $P_\Omega = \int_\Omega \mathrm{d}\pi_A$ is a bounded operator.

Note that when the operator has continuous spectrum, then single points in the continuous spectrum have zero measure: There is strictly speaking no projector $\lvert x\rangle\langle x\rvert$ onto an eigenspace with value $x$ for the position operator, but there is the projector $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\lvert x\rangle\langle x\rvert$ onto states with position between $x_1$ and $x_2$ for any $x_1\neq x_2$.

Note that in order to talk about $C^\ast$-algebras for unbounded operators $A$, the easier way to get bounded operators out of them is to talk about their exponentiated versions $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}At}$, with which they are in one-to-one correspondence via Stone's theorem.

Comment: Thank you @ACuriousMind. So the logic is that, since $e^{i A t}$ is bounded it is in the C*-algebra, and moreover it also shares the same set of "approximated" eigenstates with $A$. Am I right?

Comment: @MBlrd Yes (but I really wouldn't think about this in terms of "approximate" eigenstates, the claim that some version of those exists is true but not all that useful)